# Issue in rendering items conditionally on navigation bar in core ui vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, core-ui

I am making a website using vue.js and coreui. The question is i have 2 kinds of user on this website (i.e Admin and Users). What I hope is in the navigation bar when user->(users) is logged in only certain items on the navbar are added. How do I achieve this? I have been reading the documentation and I found no lucks.

I don't know how to override this sidebar template I did tried directly changing @coreui files but it's not reflecting.

Any helps would be appreciated.
Thank You

_nav.js

```
export default {
    items: [
        {
            name: 'Dashboard',
            url: '/dashboard',
            icon: 'icon-speedometer',
            badge: {
                variant: 'primary',
                text: 'NEW'
            }
        },
        {
            title: true,
            name: 'Administrator',
            class: '',
            wrapper: {
                element: '',
                attributes: {}
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'PRC',
            url: '/priority',
            icon: 'icon-layers',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'PRC Types',
                    url: '/priority',
                    icon: 'icon-puzzle'
                },
                {
                    name: 'PRC Range',
                    url: '/priority/range',
                    icon: 'icon-directions'
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            name: 'Users',
            url: '/users',
            icon: 'icon-user'
        },
        {
            name: 'SubTenant',
            url: '/tenant',
            icon: 'icon-user'
        },
        {
            name: 'Groups',
            url: '/groups',
            icon: 'icon-list'
        },
        {
            name: 'TaskList',
            url: '/tasklist',
            icon: 'icon-list'
        },
        {
            name: 'ProcessList',
            url: '/process',
            icon: 'icon-list'
        },
    ]
}
```

main.js

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import 'core-js/es6/promise'
import 'core-js/es6/string'
import 'core-js/es7/array'
// import cssVars from 'css-vars-ponyfill'
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import VueAuth from '@websanova/vue-auth'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
import Element from 'element-ui'

Vue.use(Element);
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/client';
Vue.router  = router;
Vue.use(VueAuth, {
    auth: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/auth/bearer.js'),
    http: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x.js'),
    router: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.js'),
    tokenDefaultName:"token",
    tokenStore: ['localStorage', 'cookie'],
    authRedirect: {path: '/auth'},
    notFoundRedirect: {path: '/dashboard'},
    fetchData:{url : "auth" , method : "GET"},
    refreshData:{enabled:false}
  });

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  mounted(){
  },
  methods: {
  },
  components: {
    App
  }
});
```

And I am not searching for how I do this portion.

Comment: Can you add the link of documentation you are referring??

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625394/show-only-certain-items-at-certain-condition-on-navigation-bar-in-core-ui-vue-js

Comment: But I am not able to override template do you know how I can do this?

Comment: In coreui I am not getting documentation for override template and I did tried to change into main file also but I don't know what;s going on wrong with that.

Comment: You don't need to override ,just nee to add v-if and v-else for conditional rendering as below. <template v-if="user=='admin'">code for admin navbar</template><template v-else>code for users navbar</template>

Comment: where I need to put this condition can you please help me?

Comment: bcoz In sidebar while I am going to add like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625394/show-only-certain-items-at-certain-condition-on-navigation-bar-in-core-ui-vue-js?answertab=votes#tab-top this it's not affecting my navigation menus

Comment: Can u add your code here so that i can help you with that.

Comment: Now you know what I have updated code and added _nav.js but my node_module @coreui not updating I have added or remove code from there also but it's showing as it is I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Where is the template rendering code ?

Comment: I have already updated code and added render template code now from where i can.

Comment: @Riddhi I have resolve this we have to override core ui sidebar, before I was taking from node_module coreui that's why it was not effecting now it's work. Thank you for your help.